# Quotes in sed when used in bash script

Tags: bash, regex, sed

I am generating sed expression in Bash script, and I am having a following problem.

I want to add a space in front of each appearance of abc.

This commands works as expected

```
echo abc | sed -e "s/abc/ def/"
```

output is *" def*" without quotes

whereas this commands

```
Q='-e "s/abc/ def/"'
echo abc | sed $Q
```

outputs *sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'*

Outside of bash script, everything works.

I tried all possible ways of quotes, escaping characters, but couldn't figure it out. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of options, not a single one:

```
Q=( -e "s/abc/ def/" )
echo abc | sed "${Q[@]}"
```